# How to get current_user from Flask Login to return a logged in user when using Pytest?

Tags: flask, pytest, flask-login, flask-security

I'm testing a login view from a Flask application using Pytest. The login view is generated by Flask Security.

When I log in the user either by posting data to the login route or by calling the login_user method, the current_user object is set to AnonymousUser instead of returning the logged-in user.

Pytest fixtures

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_client():

    flask_app = create_app(TestingConfig)
    testing_client = flask_app.test_client()

    ctx = flask_app.app_context()
    ctx.push()

    yield testing_client  # this is where the testing happens!

    ctx.pop()


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_db(test_client):
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()

    yield db

    db.drop_all()
    try:
        os.remove("app.db")
    except e as e:
        pass
```

Pytest test

```
from uuid import uuid4

import pytest
from app.models import User
from flask import current_app
from flask_login import current_user
from flask_security.utils import encrypt_password, login_user

def test_login_route(test_client, test_db):
    email = "test@123.com"
    password = "passwordtoencrypt"
    encrypted_password = encrypt_password(password)
    id = uuid4()
    user = User(email=email, password=encrypted_password, id=id)
    user = user.save()
    test_db.session.commit()

    with current_app.test_request_context():
        response = test_client.post(
            "/login",
            data=dict(email="test@123.com", password=password),
            follow_redirects=True,
        )

        assert current_user.email == email #Failing assert statement
```

And user model

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    """User model"""

    id = db.Column(
        UUIDType, unique=True, nullable=False, default=uuid4(), primary_key=True
    )
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship(
        "Role", secondary=roles_users, backref=db.backref("users", lazy="dynamic")
    )
```

This correctly logs the user in but doesn't set the current_user object correctly.

I'm expecting my assert statement to succeed, however it throws the error `E       AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'email'`

Comment: I don't know what's the default content type flask test client sets, but you can try setting it explicitly, e.g. `test_client.post(data, content_type='multipart/form-data', ...)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it doesn't solve the issue but it's indeed probably good practice to send it explicitly

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing 2 concepts together in a single test - both faking a request context as well as actually initiating a request. I believe over the long term - this will really complicate your tests.
The `current_app.test_request_context` will push a request context, then your actual "/login" request will push another request context. That one will set `current_user` but once that request context is popped (at end of request) - `current_user` will be reset.
A question is - why would you be testing flask-security? If you want to test that login works - then check the response.status_code - or after logging in - perform another request to one of your endpoints that required authentication.

Comment: Yes you're probably right, testing an already tested module is probably not a great idea

Comment: Sorry - I didn't mean to come across as negative - more importantly, I think being careful in segmenting testing  into 'internal' - where you might need a request context *as if a real request had come in* versus external - where you are actually sending in a request and validating the response will make your tests simpler.